# jquery not quick enough to take effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a need to add a class to certain pages - ones that contain an ID of #hero. For all other pages, the class must not be added.

Because I'm using asp.net with a few layered master pages, its not as simple as just adding a class directly to the html becuase the body tag sits a couple of pages above the aspx page.

I could locate the body tag, but so far I've tried to avoid that due to the added complexity, and instead tried to use jquery.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    updateBodyClasses();

});

function updateBodyClasses() {

    if($("#hero")) {
        $("html, body").addClass("hero");

    }
}
```

Nothing complicated, but here's the rub. By the time the class has been appended, the page has been rendered and the class doesn't seem to have any effect. However, if I test it by adding the class directly to the html, it works - so I know the CSS works and that its a timing issue.

I suppose I could add the code higher up the page - jquery is deferred, so I would need to know the equivalent javascript to try it out.

Would appreciate any thoughts on this potential solution, or perhaps and other ideas.

/* UPDATE */

For clarity, it seems to be the HTML related class that isn't being applied.

Comment: Try: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {document.body.classList.add('hero');});`

Comment: offtopic: `$("#hero")` will always resolve to `true`

Comment: If you have an ID "hero" why do you want a class "hero", too?

Comment: @blgt even if #hero isn't present in the page ?

Comment: blgt - this doesn't seem to be the case, the changes don't kick in when #hero is not on the page.

Comment: GhitaB - because #hero applies to a DIV embedded on the page, and I need to apply some CSS to the HTML and BODY tags.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen Yes. It'll return an empty jQuery collection, which is resolved to a boolean `true`. @JohnOhara Then there's something else preventing your class from working. The condition as written does nothing

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen - you are quite right, it is adding the class, which led me to believe it was working, but it also applied the class to pages without the #.

Comment: There could be a couple of scenarios that may prevent this from working.
1) May be when you're `addClass`ing, the respective CSS file may not have been loaded. Try moving this script to the bottom of the page.

Comment: 2) There may some error in other scripts that causes this script to not execute at all

Comment: Also, your condition is semantically wrong. If you want to see if the element with `id="hero"` exists, then the right way to do it is `if($('#hero').length)` not just `if($('#hero')` :)

Comment: @Maverick - the script is at the bottom, using a deferred script to loans after jquery has finished. The CSS is long since loaded.

Comment: @Maverick - thanks for the update.

Comment: @Tushar - where would I place this code and how would it be called?

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the DOM without waiting for it to be ready.

You need to:

- load jQuery in a synchronous way(without defer or async).
- Put `#hero` element i above the script.

Please consider this example:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero">I don't care about DOM being ready</div>
<script>
  var $el = $('#hero');
  if ($el.length) {
    $el.addClass('red');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIFE(Immidiately Invocked Function Expression):

like:

```
(function()
{
 if($("#hero")) {
            $("html, body").addClass("hero");      
    }
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

just put your function in document ready like

```
$(function(){        
        if($("#hero")) {
            $("html, body").addClass("hero");      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No real solution provided.

Not reasitic to change the whole site infrastructure - from one that defers jquery to loading it synchronously.

The two other jquery answers are as per the current setup and don't work.

The only working solution was provided by Tushar, although it would still require selective loading of the script, which was not included in the answer.

In the end, I used a workaround, which bypassed the need for any javascript. Instead of selectively adding a class to html tag, I added the css permanently to the html tag, affecting all pages. I then added an inner div, which reverses it out. This means that any page can now manipulate its own functionality directly without having to add classes to the html tag.